# UAC dialog kills my VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse, uac

After recent Virtual Machine updates, none of my VirtualBox operates normally. They start up fine until I need to install something. I have narrowed it down to UAC dialog. Once it comes up (which takes unsually long time), I can't operate the mouse or keyboard. I can't respond to the dialog.

The mouse sometimes does appear and mouse cursor seems to be disconnected with mouse. Even if I manage to bring the cursor on OK, and click, it doesn't reigster.

I have uninstalled Virtual Machine, re-installed it but didn't help. I have removed all Virtual Boxes and added one back but didn't help.

The problem seems to be that VM is 5.2.22 and guest editions on VB is a version older. But I need to respond to UAC dialog to updated gueset editions so I am stuck!

**Update**

I uninstalled extention pack, then virtual box and deleted the c:\Users\.VirtualBox folder so remove it complete and reintalled it. It still has issues but severity has come down.

The UAC dialog still hangs the system but the trick that works is I press the close button in Virtual Box but when close dialog appears, I press cancel. This somehow makes the VB respond again and I was able to press Ok button on UAC. It still took a very long time to install (+40 minutes) but at leasts its not as worse.

Briging regedit also freezes the systsem when UAC appears but the same tricks works, close to VB but then cancel it and UI is responsive again.

Comment: Since you are using Windows 7, you can disable UAC, and install the required software within the VM.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @Ramhound My host is Windows 7 but the Virtual Boxes are Windows 7 and 8. I would have to disable that inside Windows 7 guest VirtualBox but not sure if it will effect the other?

Comment: I started a Windows 7 guest VB but without doing anything, its slow. I can't drag Virtual Machine smoothly as its busy. It seems like something else is wrong.

Comment: You are disabling UAC within the VM anyways.

Comment: For using virtual box, you need to disable UAC, as a workaround to not disable UAC, we could use Hyper-v

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem, with a windows 8 guest in virtualbox in 6.1.30 on OS X Monterey. As soon as the windows guest triggers the user account control dialog to give elevated permission, the virtual machine becomes unresponsive to input. Often eventually triggering a critical crash in virtualbox.

Just maybe got it to work. While it was running, I disabled the 'scaled-mode' display, which switched it to the auto-resize; display mode. I then turned off mouse integration in the input menu.

This allowed  me to turn off UAC via the control panel in  windows.

Had to remove loads of dump files filled GB's disk space before I could run auslogic's disk defrag, which was the original purpose of the exercise!